# MongoMapper - NameError (uninitialized constant User::Message)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

Ruby - 1.9.2
Rails - 3.1.1
MongoMapper - 0.9.1

Very weird. This code used to work fine. All of a sudden when you have things like this, it breaks:

```
class MyClass
  def self.test
    MyClass.all
  end
end
```

So I changed them to:

```
class MyClass
  def self.test
    self.all
  end
end
```

And that fixed it, but now it's spawned this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant User::Message)
```

for this code:

```
def get_messages_with_user(user)
   all_messages = Message.where(:$or => [{:sender_id => self.id, :recipient_id => user.id, :is_active => true}, {:sender_id => user.id, :recipient_id => self.id, :is_active => true}]).sort(:created_at.asc).all

   all_messages.reject{ |message| message.sender == self && message.introducer_id.present? }
end
```

Any idea what that means??? The worst part is, if we deploy to Heroku, it doesn't happen. Only happens locally...

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though something with requiring files is not right on our dev sytems.

Doing:

```
::Message.where...
```

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is working on Heroku? Check the logs.